# Activity id propagation in REST services

Tags: .net, wcf, rest, logging, etw

WCF has a mechanism to propagate activity ids for logging between service calls. How is this supposed to work when there are REST services in the call stack?

Is there a standard HTTP header in which this information should be sent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of any standards but from my previous discussions on this subject, `correlation-id` seems to be the preferred term.

Answer (score 2):

This list of HTTP header fields on Wikipedia doesn't provide any good candidates for sending this information.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields

It seems that Microsoft at least has solved this issue for one of their products by including a custom HTTP header:

> X-ETW-ACTIVITY-ID

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc224271.aspx

**EDIT**

In Azure, Microsoft solved the same problem using a different header:

> x-ms-activity-id

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.azure.devices.common.webapi.customheaderconstants.aspx